# Reconnect to WLAN automatically

Tags: connection-issues, wlan

Android sometimes has this strange habit of not automatically reconnecting, when it looses connection to the router. 
I have an Android tablet running 24/7 using a bot to do stuff on the Internet.
But sometimes, the connection breaks, and i have to manually click on the wlan symbol in the dropdown thingy the force android to reconnect the the router. This is annoying, because I have to check multple times a day, whether the bot is still working and reconnect if not.

This happens approximatly once/twice a week. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab SM-T230, Android 4.4.2

Does anyone know how to fix the problem/why android does that?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to fix the problem using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (paid; 7 day free trial) or [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) (free/paid) or [AutomateIt Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateItPro.mainPackage) and I don't have a reliable way to test my answer so I can't fix some flaws.

## MacroDroid

The macro would be:

- Trigger: *Wifi State Change → Disconnect from Network* → select your network
- Action: *Wifi Configure*:

  - *Connect to Network* → select your network

  or

  - *Disable Wifi*
  - *Enable Wifi*
- Constraint:

  - *Wifi State → Not Connected to Network* → select your network

  and

  - *Wifi State → Wifi Enabled*

## Tasker

Profile would be:

- Trigger: *State → Net → Wifi Connected* → check *Invert*
- Task: Action(s):

  - *Net → Wifi Net*:

    - *Action*: *Reconnect*
    - check *Force*

  or

  - *Net → WiFi → Off*
  - *Net → WiFi → On*
- Additional trigger: *Net → Wifi Near* → select *SSID* of your network

## AutomateIt Pro

The free version requires me to connect to internet (which I'm unwilling to) to unlock a feature, so perhaps, free version can also do the job here.

The rule would be:

- Trigger: *[Composite AND Trigger]*:

  - *Wifi Network Connection State Trigger*:

    - *Monitored Network*: select your network
    - *Connection State*: *Disconnected*
  - *Wifi Network Available Trigger*:

    - *Network Name*: mention the SSID of your network
    - check *In Range*
- Action: *[Composite Action]*:

  - *Set Wifi State Action → Wi-Fi Disabled*
  - *Set Wifi State Action → Wi-Fi Enabled*

That should work.